# Getting Error on page Load, The provided animation trigger "animate" has not been registered

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, angular7

I have just Updated my web application project from angular 4 to angular 7, I am facing issues with the animation trigger on my page load (ngOnInIt Method).I need to support the same animation effects which was prevailing in angular 4 with angular 7

I have added the Trigger to my app.module.ts but I couldn't able to resolve the error still

**Angular 4**

```
import {animateFactory } from 'ack-angular-fx'
```

**.ts File**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'abc',
   templateUrl: './abc.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./abc.component.css'],
   animations: [animateFactory(480, 200, 'ease-in', 100, 'animate')]
})
```

**.html File**

```
<div [@animate]="'zoomIn'">
</div>
```

**Angular 7**

**.ts**

```
import { trigger, transition, useAnimation } from '@angular/animations';
import { bounce, zoomIn } from 'ngx-animate';

@component({
  animations: [
        trigger('bounce', [transition('* => *', useAnimation(zoomIn))])
    ],
})
```

**.html**

```
<div [@animate]="'zoomIn'"></div>
```

**Actual Error Message I got is**

```
Error: The provided animation trigger "animate" has not been registered!
    at AnimationTransitionNamespace.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.AnimationTransitionNamespace._getTrigger (http://us-test-abc.ils.local:5555/vendor.js:3668:19)
    at AnimationTransitionNamespace.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.AnimationTransitionNamespace.trigger (http://us-test-abc.ils.local:5555/vendor.js:3675:28)
    at TransitionAnimationEngine.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.TransitionAnimationEngine.trigger (http://us-test-abc.ils.local:5555/vendor.js:4093:20)
    at InjectableAnimationEngine.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.AnimationEngine.process (http://us-test-abc.ils.local:5555/vendor.js:5093:36)
    at AnimationRenderer.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.AnimationRenderer.setProperty (http://us-test-abc.ils.local:5555/vendor.js:73490:29)
    at setElementProperty (http://us-test-abc.ils.local:5555/vendor.js:62483:19)
    at checkAndUpdateElementValue (http://us-test-abc.ils.local:5555/vendor.js:62434:13)
    at checkAndUpdateElementInline (http://us-test-abc.ils.local:5555/vendor.js:62383:24)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://us-test-abc.ils.local:5555/vendor.js:64732:20)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://us-test-abc.ils.local:5555/vendor.js:64698:16)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your trigger is called `bounce` (as you defined it,

```
animations: [
      trigger('bounce', [transition('* => *', useAnimation(zoomIn))])
],
```

),
so your `div` should instead look like this `<div [@bounce]="'zoomIn'"></div>`.

Try this, let me know if it still gives you trouble.